# Calling web service via url

Tags: web-services, url, jboss, wildfly

I want to know how a web service be called using a url.

I have a web service whose code looks something like this.

```
@WebService(serviceName="MyWS")
public class MyWS {
    @WebMethod(operationName="myMethod")
    public String myMethod(@Webparam(name="msg") String msg) {
        return "Hello " + msg;
    }
}
```

This is deployed in a wildfly application server.
When I type `https://HOST_IP:8443/MyWar-war/MyWS?wsdl`, it shows a xml string as response(i have used Chrome as well as Postman). However when I try to access the url `https://HOST_IP:8443/MyWar-war/MyWS/myMethod?msg=ABCXYZ` it says

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>Not Found</body>
</html>
```

Is my way of calling the method right? If not can someone please show me how to call a web service method via url?

Thanks

Comment: You can not call a SOAP Webservice via URL. You need a SOAP client

Comment: I don't know much about that. Basically I am trying to call a webservice from javascript. Can you please give me some specific example how to do that?

Comment: Read about rest servcies